# getText() not working properly

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

The code prints the input number in the new jframe, but I can't get to store anything at the variable `input` from `getText()`. Plz tell me what I am doing wrong.

My Code:-

```
  import javax.swing.*;

  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;

  public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
   {
static boolean a=false;

 public MainFrame()
{
    setTitle("Square's Root Finder");
    setSize(350,100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLookAndFeel();

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton but1 = new JButton("Calculate");
    JLabel label1= new JLabel("Enter the number:", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JTextField t = new JTextField(20);


    if (a==true)

    {
        String input = t.getText();

        System.out.print(input);
        JLabel label2=new JLabel(input);
        add(label2);
    }

    add(but1);
    add(label1);
    add(t);
    but1.addActionListener(this);

}


 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

   }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
           {

    String cmd = arg0.getActionCommand();
    if(cmd.equals("Calculate"))
    {  
        a=true;
        new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

}
       }
```

Comment: what is the output you getting and what your expected output

Comment: Sry my bad, I just edited the question, but thanks I think I got the ans thanks to @RossDrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `MainFrame` every time you press `but1` so `t` is emptied every time before it is printed out...

```
new MainFrame().setVisible(true); //calls MainFrame() while creating new object instance
...
JTextField t = new JTextField(20); //creates an empty text field
...
if (a==true)
{
  String input = t.getText(); //t has just been created so it is empty
  System.out.print(input); //t is empty so input is empty
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get anything from t, because as soon as you initialize it, you are getting it's text value (in the Constructor). It is logical that the textField will be empty. Try seperating the code of what "calculate" does from the construction of your form and put it directly in the action listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
{
    String cmd = arg0.getActionCommand();
    if(cmd.equals("Calculate"))
    {  
        String input = t.getText();
        System.out.print(input);
        label2.setText(input);
    }
}
```